# Cygwin directory scans miss files created by native tools

Tags: cygwin

I printed a web page to a file c:\temp\FILE.ps and it shows in CMD dir and icacls.  It does not show in Cygwin bash ls, despite icacls showing same permission as in a visible file beside.  Why?

Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

Symantec Endpoint Protection 12.1.6.

Cygwin 2.10.0-1.

Including an example of omission of a file from directory scans below.  Autocomplete ignores this file as well.

```
USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ ls -la FILE.ps
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER Domain Users 800271 Feb 21 11:05 FILE.ps

$ getfacl FILE.ps
# file: FILE.ps
# owner: USER
# group: Domain Users
user::rw-
group::r--
other:r--

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ ls -la *.ps
ls: cannot access '*.ps': No such file or directory

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: USER
# group: Domain Users
user::rwx
group::r-x
other:r-x

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ icacls FILE.ps
FILE.ps                     DOMAIN\USER:(F)
                            NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                            BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                            DOMAIN\USER:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ ls -al *.pdf
[...]
-rw-r--r-- 1 USER Domain Users 284295 Feb 21 12:44  FILE.pdf
[...]

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ icacls FILE.pdf
FILE.pdf                     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                             BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                             DOMAIN\USER:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files


USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ getfacl FILE.pdf
# file: FILE.pdf
# owner: USER
# group: Domain Users
user::rw-
group::r--
other:r--


USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$ ls -la | grep FILE.ps

USER@HOST /cygdrive/c/Users/USER
$
```

Comment: It should, assuming everything is configured properly. If you do an `ls -la` does it show? There has to be something permissions related otherwise - Cygwin user is wrong, etc. Given your description, without a lot more detail, it's unlikely we'll be able to help -- it's just too broad.

Comment: To my surprise (I thought I narrowed the issue to expansion of wildcards by bash), `ls -la` does not show FILE.ps, `ls -la FILE.ps` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use last cygwin snapshot

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-02/msg00162.html
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2018-02/msg00228.html

it has a correction for that issue